# Very slow mysql query despite Extra: using where; using index

Tags: mysql

I run into an interesting problem I want to understand. I have a table:

```
        `id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `user_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,

        `followers_count` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        `friends_count` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        `statuses_count` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        `favourites_count` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        `listed_count` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

        `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I execute the following query:

> SELECT `followers_count`,`friends_count`,`statuses_count`,`favourites_count`,`listed_count`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(`created_at`)) AS `id` FROM `user_track` WHERE `created_at`>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND `user_id`='1234567'

### Now, the interesting part:

**1:** With the following index on that table, the query takes several minutes to complete:

> INDEX `user_numbers` (`created_at`,`user_id`,`followers_count`,`friends_count`,`statuses_count`,`favourites_count`,`listed_count`)

Explain query with the above index 1:

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key             key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      user_track  range   user_numbers    user_numbers    12          NULL    1119318 Using where; Using index
```

**2:** However, with the following index on that table, it takes less than 200ms:

> INDEX `user_report` (`user_id`,`id`,`created_at`,`followers_count`,`friends_count`,`statuses_count`,`favourites_count`,`listed_count`)

Explain query with the above index 2:

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key             key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      user_track  ref     user_report     user_report     8           const   1       Using where; Using index
```

By explaining the query I see that the first index causes a lot of rows to be scanned, while the second index has "ref: const" and only a few rows scanned. But I would like to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on `(col1, col2, col3)`, you have indexed search capabilities on `(col1)`, `(col1, col2)`, and `(col1, col2, col3)`.
>
> MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index. Suppose that you have the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statements shown here:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1;
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2;
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2 AND col3=val3;
> ```
>
> If an index exists on `(col1, col2, col3)`, only the first two queries use the index. The third and fourth queries do involve indexed columns, but `(col2)` and `(col2, col3)` are not leftmost prefixes of `(col1, col2, col3)`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, but for me it looks like the slow index complies with the manual you quote, while the fast index doesn't - and that's what puzzles me, why the 'user_report' index works so fast despite not having a proper leftmost prefix for that query.

Comment: I've added the explain for the query on both indexes.

Comment: @f055: This is quite logical - since `user_id` is the leftmost column in the `user_report` index, MySQL can immediately locate all the records for `user_id='1234567'` (of which there's apparently only one) - it then merely need check that the resulting record satisfies the other `WHERE` criterion; whereas, using the `user_track` index, it must first find all 1,119,318 records with `created_at` in the desired date range and then check whether the `user_id` matches.  Clearly the first approach requires far less work than the second.

Comment: this makes total sense now, thanks! not sure why the optimiser even uses the user_report index though, since the WHERE clause is not in the proper order in respect to the index columns (according to the manual you quoted).

Comment: @f055: The optimiser doesn't always select the best index.  Sometimes you have to provide an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-hints.html).